# How to activate the child theme in Wordpress?

Tags: child-theme, css, parent-theme

I create a new style.css and use it in child theme. And I create a new folder in wp-content and name it as themename-child and upload the style.css that I created. Now, I go to wp dashboard -> Appearance -> Themes and I look the child theme that I create. And I found this error:

```
Broken Themes

The following themes are installed but incomplete. Themes must have a stylesheet and a     template.

Name    Description
Accesspress Lite    The parent theme is missing. Please install the "AccesspressLite" parent theme.
```

Here's the css child theme format:

```
/*
Theme Name:   Accesspress Lite
Theme URI:    http://access-keys.com/accesspresslite/
Description:  Accesspress Lite Child Theme
Author:       Yang
Author URI:   http://www.example.com
Template:     accesspress-lite
Version:      2
Tags:         blue, white, light, custom-menu, one-column, two-columns, three-columns,   left-sidebar, right-sidebar, fixed-layout, fluid-layout, custom-background, featured-image-header, sticky-post, theme-options, threaded-comments, featured-images, full-width-template, custom-header, flexible-header, responsive-layout
Text Domain:  accesspress-lite-child
*/

@import url("../accesspress-lite/style.css");
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help you out and clear up a few things. This was done for another theme, you should just change the parent theme paths accordingly

For the sake of creating a child theme and understanding what is what, I will help you here. This is how the child theme stylesheet header should look like (*or any parent theme for that matter*)

> ```
> /*
> Theme Name:   Accesspress Lite Child
> Theme URI:    http://access-keys.com/accesspresslite/
> Description:  Accesspress Lite Child Theme
> Author:       Yang
> Author URI:   http://example.com
> Template:     accesspress-lite
> Version:      2
> Tags:         blue, white, light, custom-menu, one-column, two-columns, three-columns,   left-sidebar, right-sidebar,
> fixed-layout, fluid-layout, custom-background, featured-image-header,
> sticky-post, theme-options, threaded-comments, featured-images,
> full-width-template, custom-header, flexible-header, responsive-layout
> Text Domain:  accesspress-lite-child
> */
> ```

- `Theme Name`  => The name of your child theme, can be anything to your desire
- `Theme URI`   => The path to the theme where it can be downloaded
- `Description` => Short description what your theme is all about.
- `Author`      => The person who coded the child theme
- `Author URI`  => URL to the website of the author who coded the theme
- `Template`    => The folder in which the parent themes' style.css resides
- `Version`     => self explanatory, the version to the theme
- `Tags`        => Related tags for your theme for tag search results, used on wordpress.org
- `Text Domain` => The text domain (unique identifier) that will be used by translators for translatable strings in the theme
- <strike>@import url(); => The actual path to the style.css of the parent theme</strike>

**What is needed in a child theme:**

Only the following are needed for a personal child theme that will not be distributed

- `Theme Name`
- `Template`
- `Text Domain` (only if you going to localize your theme using po and mo files)
- <strike>@import url()</strike>

### EDIT

`@import` should not be used to call the parent stylesheet, or any stylesheet for that matter. The correct way is to enqueue and register a stylesheet with `wp_enqueue_style()` and wp_register_style() hooked to `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook. This whoole method is described in my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/164120/31545)

Answer (score 1):

All the information you need can be found here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

The important parts to get it up and running would be to:

Make sure the parent theme exists (the complete accesspress-lite theme in your case)

Create a unique folder name for your child theme.

Create a style.css file in your child theme folder.

```
/*
Theme Name:   Your Child Theme Name
Theme URI:    http://access-keys.com/accesspresslite/
Description:  Accesspress Lite Child Theme
Author:       Your Name
Author URI:   http://www.your-child-theme.com
Template:     accesspress-lite
Version:      1.0
Tags:         blue, white, light, custom-menu, one-column, two-columns, three-columns,   left-sidebar, right-sidebar, fixed-layout, fluid-layout, custom-background, featured-image-header, sticky-post, theme-options, threaded-comments, featured-images, full-width-template, custom-header, flexible-header, responsive-layout
Text Domain:  accesspress-lite-child
*/
```

Make sure the Template line matches the parent them folder.

Create a functions.php file within the child theme folder. In that file, import your parent theme styles. Doing this instead of an @import in your stylesheet makes sure that the dependencies are met.

```
function child_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-styles',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( 'parent-styles' )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

Note that as a child theme, any time you use get_template_directory_uri() you're grabbing the parent theme directory. Using get_stylesheet_directory_uri() will give you the child theme directory.

Answer (score -3):

add in themename-child style.css:

```
/*
Theme Name: Your Theme
Version: 1.0
Author: Your Author
*/
```

uploat to host

Comment: I already put that but still I have an error

Comment: remove all code in style.css and add my code and view again

Comment: you add folder to wp-content or wp-content/theme/ ????

Comment: Still I have same error

Comment: wp-content/theme

Comment: in wp-content/theme/ you create news folder name: yourtheme and add one file: index.php with `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" media="screen" />` + style.css code: `/*
Theme Name: Your Theme
Version: 1.0
Author: Your Author
*/` and view in wp dashboard -> Appearance -> Themes