# WordPress + Child Theme = Am I missing something?

Tags: child-theme, parent-theme

I have an issue that has me scratching my head and if I scratch anymore I'm gonna go bald. I have looked all over for a solution but have not found anything so I thought I'd stop by and see if maybe any of you experts out there can assist.

I created a theme called WP-Forge and then I created a child theme to be used with WP-Forge called WP-Starter http://wpstarter.themeawesome.com/

When I created WP-Starter, the method of @import was still being used and now I see that there is a new way of pulling in the parent css: http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

However, when I updated WP-Starter to use this new way of pulling in the parent css, it seems that I get two versions of WP-Starter's style sheet. If you look at the source of  WP-Starter demo site listed above - you will see that wpforge-css is exactly the same as child-style-css.

In my parent theme I have all of scripts and styles enqueued in the following manner:

```
function wpforge_scripts() {

    // Enqueue our stylesheets
    wp_enqueue_style('opensans-style', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,600');
    wp_enqueue_style('font-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/fonts/wpforge-fonts.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('normalize-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/normalize.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('foundation-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/foundation.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('wpforge-style', get_stylesheet_uri());    

    // Register our scripts
    wp_enqueue_script ('modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/vendor/modernizr.js', array('jquery'), '5.5.0.3', false);
    wp_enqueue_script ('foundation-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/foundation.min.js', array('jquery'), '5.5.0.3', true);
    wp_enqueue_script ('functions-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/wpforge-functions.js', array('jquery'), '5.5.0.3', true);

    // Make the "Back" string in Foudation mobile menu translatable
    $translation_array = array( 'nav_back' => __( 'Back', 'wpforge' ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'foundation-js', 'foundation_strings', $translation_array );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpforge_scripts' );
```

and in my child theme WP-Starter all I have is this:

```
function wpstarter_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpstarter_styles', 100 );
```

Now when you look at the page source of the demo site you will see this:

```
<title>WP-Starter | A WordPress Child Theme for WP-Forge</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wpforge-fonts-css'  href='http://wpstarter.themeawesome.com/wp-content/themes/wp-forge/fonts/wpforge-fonts.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='normalize-css'  href='http://wpstarter.themeawesome.com/wp-content/themes/wp-forge/css/normalize.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='foundation-css'  href='http://wpstarter.themeawesome.com/wp-content/themes/wp-forge/css/foundation.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wpforge-css'  href='http://wpstarter.themeawesome.com/wp-content/themes/wpstarter/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='parent-style-css'  href='http://wpstarter.themeawesome.com/wp-content/themes/wp-forge/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='child-style-css'  href='http://wpstarter.themeawesome.com/wp-content/themes/wpstarter/style.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

If you click on wpforge-css it is the same as child-style-css.

Just wondering if anyone has ever run into this particular issue or if anyone can help by explaining why this may be happening so I can correct it?

Your help is greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you must have the unnecessary `wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array( 'parent-style' ) );` incorrectly mentioned in the Codex hanging around somewhere... (also your child `wp_enqueue_scripts` should have default priority).

Comment: @bonger I went and remove that line in the codex.

Comment: @PieterGoosen I see your previous correct stuff, based on [your answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/167643/57034), got overwritten by various other editors (it just doesn't make sense to me to have the codex so open to modification willy-nilly but anyway...sigh!).

Answer (score 1):

Actually @Pieter Goosen took care of the issue when he corrected the Codex and removed the call to the extra style sheet. So in fact this works the way it should

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
 function theme_enqueue_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
```

Thanks Pieter.

Comment: My pleasure, really don't know who went and change the Codex. I have written a post on that issue and that someone ignored it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the next line of code as it says in the codex?

**Codex:**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
 function theme_enqueue_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
   wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array( 'parent-style' ) );//Add this to wpstarter_styles();
}
```

Comment: The codex is wrong. I went and changed it to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've worked with child themes but I presume the problem here is that you're registering your parent css using `get_stylesheet_uri` as opposed to `get_template_directory_uri`

Try using this instead, notice how I have changed the `get_stylesheet_uri` with `get_template_directory_uri`

```
function wpforge_scripts() {

    // Enqueue our stylesheets
    wp_enqueue_style('opensans-style', 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,600');
    wp_enqueue_style('font-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/fonts/wpforge-fonts.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('normalize-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/normalize.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('foundation-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/foundation.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('wpforge-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');    

    // Register our scripts
    wp_enqueue_script ('modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/vendor/modernizr.js', array('jquery'), '5.5.0.3', false);
    wp_enqueue_script ('foundation-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/foundation.min.js', array('jquery'), '5.5.0.3', true);
    wp_enqueue_script ('functions-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/wpforge-functions.js', array('jquery'), '5.5.0.3', true);

    // Make the "Back" string in Foudation mobile menu translatable
    $translation_array = array( 'nav_back' => __( 'Back', 'wpforge' ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'foundation-js', 'foundation_strings', $translation_array );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpforge_scripts' );
```

Now the parent stylesheet is loaded properly we can call the child theme's stylesheet using `get_stylesheet_uri` and pass it a dependency of the parent theme stylesheet referenced by the handle it was registered with of `wpforge-style`

```
function wpstarter_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-starter', get_stylesheet_uri(), array( 'wpforge-style' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpstarter_styles', 100 );
```

This is because `get_stylesheet_uri` gets the current active themes stylesheet URI. Therefore when the child theme is loaded first it performs the function `wpforge_scripts` from its parent theme - which in your code specified `get_stylesheet_uri` thus was actually getting the URI of the child theme as that is active, not the parent theme. Swapping this for get_template_directory_uri will get the correct template directory for the parent theme.

All this is in theory I haven't had a chance to check it for you (fingers crossed)