# child index.php does not overwrite parent index.php in twenty fourteen theme

Tags: child-theme, theme-twenty-fourteen

I am using the twenty fourteen theme to create a child theme and want to make changes to the index.php, but when I copy the index.php file to the child theme's directory and edit it, it doesn't change my theme at all.
Am I doing something wrong or missing something out?
Thanks for any help

[image: screenshot of child theme folder with index.php]

I have the following code to my child theme style sheet:

```
/*
Theme Name: Twenty Fourteen Child
Theme URI: http://wordpress.org/themes/twentyfourteen
Description: Child theme - Ecuador Travel Agency Tours Site
Author: Sarah Wyatt
Author URI: http://www.onestopsolutionswebmasters.com/
Template: twentyfourteen
Version: 1.0
Tags:
*/
```

And the following code to the child theme functions.php:

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array('parent-style')
    );
}


?>
```

Comment: did you activate your child theme? what type of page are you trying to view?

Comment: Hi Sarah, welcome to WPSE and the SE network :-). Just a few tips to get you started. If you add code in the editor, highlight that code and look in the top right corner above the editor, there is a `{}` sign, click on that. That will add your code in a code block. Feel free to see [ask] and visit [help] for site related questions. Also, feel free to take a [tour] and learn how the SE sites operates

Comment: what is the changed code in index.php of your child theme?

Answer (score 0):

The way you enqueueing your stylesheets are **wrong**. Someone very ignorant keeps changing my edit in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). The way you are doing this loads your child stylesheet **twice**. I have already done a post on this that you should check out [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/167643/31545)

The correct way is

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

}
```

As for the problem with your `index.php`, you should clear all your caches, browser and plugin caches. This really seems like a cache problem as your code looks fine