# wp_enqueue_style referencing parent theme

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, child-theme, parent-theme

I have properly set up a child theme and am adding stylesheets and scripts in my new functions.php file. The only problem is, my newly enqueued stylesheets are being referenced using the parent theme when the files are located in the child theme folder.

Setting up child theme:

```
<?php
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_theme_styles', PHP_INT_MAX);
    function enqueue_child_theme_styles() {
      wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-theme', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
      wp_enqueue_style( 'child-theme', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('parent-theme')  );
    }
?>
```

Adding new styles further into my child's functions.php file:

```
<?php
function new_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'grid', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/grid.css');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'new_scripts' );
```

Which shows up this way in my  when rendered:

```
<link media="all" type="text/css" href="/wp-content/themes/parent-theme/css/grid.css?ver=4.2.2" id="grid-css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I need it to reference href="/wp-content/themes/child-theme/css/grid.css?ver=4.2.2"

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `wp_enqueue_style( 'grid', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/grid.css');`

Comment: The method you are using to enqueue the parent style is wrong. Wish that the person who constantly changes the codex would get a cramp :-). [This](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/167643/31545) is the correct method. In your `new_script()` function, `get_template_directory_uri()` should be `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`

Comment: Thanks for the update on the codex. When I was first learning to use a child theme they had just stopped using @import and I couldn't find a consensus anywhere on the correct methodology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri();` while enqueuing the scripts and styles. It returns the directory path in which your child stylesheet is stored.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick note, if you include the `PHP_INT_MAX` variable in your `add_action` call, the child theme will not work correctly!

Do NOT do this ...

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_theme_styles', PHP_INT_MAX);
```

You should rather do this ...

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_theme_styles');
```

Then it will import the child theme correctly.

Comment: Can you explain, in the question, why `PHP_INT_MAX` will not work?

Comment: I don't know ... I found the answer somewhere else, so I thought that I would share it here.