# My child theme CSS get called twice

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I accidentally discovered that my child theme CSS is get called twice. I found that this is an old issue (see [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/167918/25187) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/167639/25187)), but I don't know how to solve it in my situation.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='parent-style-css'  href='http://infopsi.md/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/style.css?ver=4.8.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='child-style-css'  href='http://infopsi.md/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/style.css?ver=0.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='twentyseventeen-style-css'  href='http://infopsi.md/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/style.css?ver=4.8.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

This is the function that I use to enqueue the parent and child theme stylesheets:

```
/** Enqueue the parent and child theme stylesheets **/
if ( !function_exists( 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' ) ):
    function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
        $parent_style = 'parent-style';
        wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
            array( $parent_style ),
            wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
        );
    }
endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

I tried to add the `wp_dequeue_style( 'twentyseventeen-style' );` to the function, but this doesn't solved the issue. **Any suggestions?**

Comment: the child `style.css` can be called by the parent theme (in parent `functions.php`) then just remove the call in the child `functions.php`

Comment: @mmm So simple? The part `wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', ...` is not  needed? I removed that part from my function and it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to enqueue your child theme's stylesheet. The parent theme does that for you. TwentySeventeen has this line:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'twentyseventeen-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
```

That's still going to run, but `twentyseventeen-style` is now your child theme's stylesheet. You just need to enqueue the parent theme's stylesheet:

```
/** Enqueue the parent and child theme stylesheets **/
if ( !function_exists( 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' ) ):
    function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
        $parent_style = 'parent-style';
        wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_parent_theme_file_uri( 'style.css' ) );
    }
endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

(I swapped your use of the template directory function for `get_parent_theme_file_uri()` because more people should know about the new theme file functions).